# Bounded sequence with a unique cluster point converges

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to prove that if a sequence $(x_n)_n$ bounded in $R$ is convergent iff has only one cluster point.

I know that if it's convergent then it has to have just one cluster point but i don't know how to prove the other side. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $x$ be the unique cluster point of $(x_n)$. Suppose $x_n$ does not tend to $x$. Then there exists $\epsilon >0$ and integers $n_1<n_2<\cdots$ such that $|x_{n_k}-x| >\epsilon$ $\,\,\,$(1)for all $k$. Now $(x_{n_k})$ is a bounded sequence. Hence it has a convergent subsequence. Its limit cannot be $x$ because of (1). This would give a cluster point for $(x_n)$ other than $x$. This is a contradiction. Hence $(x_n)$ is convergent.

Answer (score 1):

If $(x_n)$ is bounded , then the set $C$ of the cluster points of $(x_n)$ is not empty (Bolzano- Weierstraß) and bounded, furthermore

$\lim \sup x_n = \max C$ and $ \lim \inf x_n = \min C.$

If $C=\{x\}$, then $\lim \sup x_n = \lim \inf x_n ,$ hence $(x_n)$ is convergent.